# How is $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+\left | x \right |}$ continuously differentiable everywhere?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\displaystyle f(0)=\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=0$, therefore $f(x)$ is continuous?

What about differentiability? Please help i'm trying to get a hang of these concepts. Many thanks.

Comment: Sure, $0=f(0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-}f(x)$ makes the function continuous.  To check differentiability, try the limit definition of the derivative.  You'll need to check from the left and right in that limit too.

Comment: Was taking $0$ correct ? Or should i have checked it with any constant $a$?

Comment: @Idkwoman The numerator and denominator are both continuous everywhere, and the denominator is never zero. Therefore the quotient is continuous everywhere.

Comment: What's the interval?

Comment: @Zizou23 $x$ is any real number.

Comment: $\displaystyle f(0)=\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=0$ means that $f$ is continuous *at zero*.

Comment: The reason we check at $0$ is because this function can be converted into a piecewise function breaking at $0$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
f^\prime(x)&=&\frac{1\cdot(1+\vert x\vert)-x\left(\dfrac{\vert x\vert}{x}\right)}{(1+\vert x\vert)^2}\\
&=&\frac{1}{(1+\vert x\vert)^2}
\end{eqnarray}

which is both defined and continuous at $x=0$, the only place in the domain where continuity might be in question.

Answer (score 2):

Use the limit definition of the derivative:

$f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ f(0+h) - f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ \frac{h}{1+|h|} - 0 }{h}= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{1+|h|} = 1$.

Comment: Since $0$ is not mentioned in the question, and we have to prove the differentiabilit $everywhere$, should i calculate $f'(a)$ instead, and solve in a similar way?

Comment: For $a\not=0$, you can drop the absolute value bars (or replace them with multiplication by negative $1$) and the derivative of a quotient exists if the denominator is nonzero.

Comment: It's a composition of smooth functions away from $0$, so $0$ is the only place you need to check.

Comment: Got it! Many thanks!!